# Why do we need to use such a difficult way to add a stylesheet

Tags: css, html, xhtml

Why do we have a such difficult way to add a stylesheet to a page?

I mean javascript we add like

```
<script src="nope.js"></script>
```

and inline is

```
<script>
    alert("I refuse.");
</script>
```

but styles is a story apart inline is

```
<style>

    * {
        color:white;
        background:white;
    }

</style>
```

and a file is

```
 <link href="/themes/black-wide.css?r=2408" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Why do we need to use link?
isn't it more logical to use

```
<style src="style.css"></style>
```

instead of link?

Why is this like that?

**EDIT**

just to make it more clear.

*WHY in do we need to use link instead of style to point to a css file.*

Comment: In HTML5, you can drop the `type="text/css"`.

Comment: @j08691 Assuming a new stylesheet type is never created in the future =P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you think about it, `<link>` is actually much more versatile than `<style>` would be. You have to remember this part of the spec was defined in the early days of the internet, before CSS was even in use much (if at all).

I think the folks at the W3C, when they set this standard, intentionally left room for other uses of the `<link>` tag besides stylesheets. Semantically, `link` just means some reference to an external resource. Those uses may not have ever arisen, but there is room for them here. Perhaps the better question is why don't we use the `link` tag to load scripts, as well.

Comment: but why doesn't it work like that with `<script>` then?

Comment: @EaterOfCorpses Because, as it was said in multiple answers, thats not how the W3C spec was written.

Comment: @Jeremy1026 I know, I know, I know. but I want the answer why it wasn't written like that.

Comment: @EaterOfCorpses Only way to get that answer is to talk to the people that wrote it originally, StackOverflow isn't those people.

Comment: @Jeremy1026 but people on SO may know these people and info about it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the reason for `<link>` has to do with the extra features that `<link>` provides for linking an external resource.  For example, you can use `rel="alternate stylesheet"` to provide a secondary style sheet for the site.  Or, `media="print"` for a stylesheet intended for printing only, etc.

More importantly, CSS has kind of being this evolving creature from the days of old table-based layouts.  Which do you think came first `<link>` or `<style>`?

Answer (score 0):

Your point on inline styles is misguided. As you can write an inline style like:

```
<style>*{color:white;background:white;}</style>
```

The extra lines and spacing is just to aid in readability. The same can be said about inline javascript, so long as proper syntax is used one could put as many spaces and line breaks in as they wish. For an example:

```
<script>
    alert("I refuse.");
</script>
```

Would work in the same way as:

```
<script>


    alert(
          "I refuse."
         );


</script>
```

As for the syntax of using `<link...>` rather than a more simple `<style src...>` comes back to W3C and the standards that they have set. In time these standards may change to allow a shorter notation, but until that happens (if it ever does) its a minor inconvience we have to live with.

Comment: I know about dropping newlines and such its more about WHY in Jon Skeet's name do we need to use link instead of style to point to a file?

Comment: If you're not targeting legacy browsers you can use this syntax if you prefer it `<style type="text/css">@import url("styles.css");</style>`.

Comment: @user17753 thanks :) that is a way I like :)